# Casting of Generic List to a Class derived from a List

Tags: c#

I created a class derived from List. However when I tried casting the class to another List object I get a runtime error. My code is similar to the one posted below:

```
public class CategoryObj
{
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class CategoryObjCollection:List<CategoryObj>
{

}

public void Test()
{
        CategoryObjCollection cat = new CategoryObjCollection();
        using (NWDataContext db = new NWDataContext())
        {
            var qry = (from c in db.Categories
                       select new CategoryObj
                       {
                           CategoryID = c.CategoryID,
                           CategoryName = c.CategoryName,
                           Description = c.Description
                       }).ToList();
            cat = (CategoryObjCollection)qry; //runtime error Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[WindowsFormsApplication1.CategoryObj]' to type 'WindowsFormsApplication1.CategoryObjCollection'.
        }
}
```

I hope someone can help me on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

Why would you expect to be able to cast? The object *isn't* an instance of `CategoryObjCollection`. The point of reference type casts (when they're actually casting rather than invoking explicit conversions) is to tell the compiler that you believe the *execution time* type of the object is actually compatible with the type you specify, so that you can use members of that specific type (after the execution time test). In this case, the `ToList` extension method just creates a new `List<T>`.

More to the point, what is your `CategoryObjCollection` type meant to achieve in the first place? If it has any state other than the normal list, where would you expect that state to come from after your LINQ query? If it doesn't have any other state, is it really adding any benefit? Maybe your type should actually *contain* a list rather than deriving from it? Then you could create a new instance of the type using the results of the query.

In general, it's usually a design smell to derive from `List<T>`. It doesn't provide many ways to specialize its "listiness" (unlike, say, `Collection<T>`). It's usually a sign that you should be thinking of composition instead of inheritance.

Comment: Looks to me that he is trying to do a C++-like typedef alias.

Comment: @Jaroslav: Quite possibly - but that's not what inheritance is, and it's not what it should be used for.

Comment: Indeed. That's what the `using` directive is for.

Answer (score 6):

try this

```
public class CategoryObjCollection:List<CategoryObj>
{
   public CategoryObjCollection(IEnumerable<CategoryObj> items) : base(items){}
}


cat = new CategoryObjCollection(qry);
```

Answer (score 3):

The cast would only work if you have implemented a conversion operator. But it is not a very effective approach.

Are you trying to create a type alias (like in C++ typedef)?

```
using CategoryObjCollection = System.Collections.Generic.List<myNamespace.CategoryObj>;
```

Now you can freely convert between `CategoryObjCollection` and `List<CategoryObj>` (which is the same type - only named differently.

I would also use a different method to fill the list up:

```
db.Categories.ForEach(c =>
    cat.Add(new CategoryObj()
        {
            CategoryID = c.CategoryID,
            CategoryName = c.CategoryName,
            Description = c.Description
        }));
```

Answer (score 0):

why are you casting ? You actually shouldn't be casting ....just add a loop over `qry` and fill your `cat` list up.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this **Extension Method**

```
public static M Cast<T, M>(this IEnumerable<T> input) where M : ICollection<T>, new()
{
  var ret = new M();
  foreach(var item in input?? Enumerable.Empty<T>())
  {
    ret.Add(item);
  }
  return ret;
}
```

then you can use it like

```
var qry = (from c in db.Categories
   select new CategoryObj
   {
       CategoryID = c.CategoryID,
       CategoryName = c.CategoryName,
       Description = c.Description
    }).Cast<CategoryObj,CategoryObjCollection>()
```