# Cast generic list to inherited class

Tags: c#, linq, generic-list

Is it possible cast list to class which inherited list?

Example

```
public class FooCollection : List<Foo>
{
}

List<Foo> oFooList = new List<Foo>();
FooCollection oColl =  (FooCollecton)oFooList;
```

I expect that last line would work but it isn't.

PS: I will use that to cast linq result to cast inherited collection. Any help appreciated.

```
FooCollection oColl =  (FooCollecton)oDBClass.Where(x=> x.Id == 1).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't downcast anything in C#. A `Dog` is an `Animal`, but not every `Animal` is a `Dog`.

If you want to be able to cast a `List<Foo>` to `FooCollection`, you'll need to add an implicit or explicit conversion from the former in the latter. Or add a constructor with a parameter `IEnumerable<Foo>` and call `base(IEnumerable<T> items)` with that parameter.

You shouldn't inherit `List<T>` anyway.

Anyway try searching, see [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3175321/casting-of-generic-list-to-a-class-derived-from-a-list).